# Codeigniter 2.1 - MySQL and regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, codeigniter

I have code like this:

```
   function mgl_get_by($col,$id)
            {    
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('global_info');
            $this->db->join('ad', 'id_ad = id_global_info');
            $this->db->where('info_type_id', 1);
            $this->db->where($col, $id);
            $this->db->or_where("$col REGEXP $id");
            $this->db->order_by('paid', 'desc');
            $this->db->order_by('date_created', 'desc');  
            $q = $this->db->get();        
            return $q = $q->result_array();   
    }
```

**$col** is name of the row in the table, and **$id** is unique id for the query.
In most cases it is unique number, but I have date row in this table, and in the table it is inserted as timestamp, but when performing query it need to select all matches for the selected day (for example it needs to select all data from 2012-06-11). How can I do this (I am not familiar with REGEXP)?

Comment: Could you explain further what you're trying to do here? It's very unclear why you are providing the name of a row to match against an id. What's the structure of your tables? Is the date stored as an actual DATE value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need RegExp here - `LIKE` would be just fine. If your date is stored as timestamp, you should do `FROM_UNIXTIME($col) LIKE '2012-06-11'`

**EDIT**: Although, it is not efficient. Better way is to compare timestamp as an integer:

```
$col >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-06-11 00:00:00') AND $col < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-06-12 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Well this is an embracing situation. There is an easy way to do it, but I wanted to do it the hard way. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: This is pretty horrible.  You are attempting to compare 2 numbers which is something that sql does well.  This solution converts the numbers to text for comparison, that conversion is not able to get indexed (and doesn't necessarily happen correctly), and you wind up making sql do all kinds of unnecessary work.  See: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen this done with REGEXP.

If you want everything on a certain day, what you really want is:
2012-06-11 <= (date) AND  (date) < 2012-06-12

Check the $col, if it's your date column, do the date range, if it's not, do the where clause you already have.